# Error in 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524::detail::BlobManager::allocateBlobsForLayer'

Tags: python, opencv

I have this code:

```
import cv2
from cv2 import dnn_superres

# initialize super resolution object
sr = dnn_superres.DnnSuperResImpl_create()

# read the model
path = 'EDSR_x2.pb'
sr.readModel(path)
# set the model and scale
sr.setModel('edsr', 2)

sr.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
sr.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA)

image = cv2.imread('sample.png')
# upsample the image
upscaled = sr.upsample(image2)
# save the upscaled image
cv2.imwrite('upscaled_test.png', upscaled)
```

I get back this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 3
      1 image = cv2.imread('sample.png')
      2 # upsample the image
----> 3 upscaled = sr.upsample(image2)
      4 # save the upscaled image
      5 cv2.imwrite('upscaled_test.png', upscaled)

error: OpenCV(4.6.0) d:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\legacy_backend.hpp:295: error: (-215:Assertion failed) ld.inputBlobs[0]->total() == total(shapes[index]) in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20220524::detail::BlobManager::allocateBlobsForLayer'
```

The image that fails is shape (3300, 5100, 3) while the image that works OK has the shape of (443, 705, 3). Why is that happening?

Comment: How much GPU memory do you have?  That's a 50MB image.  If you convert to floats, it's 400MB.  How far are you "upscaling" it?